# javac how to compile whole source dir with wildcard?

Tags: java, javac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How can I compile an entire directory structure of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764768/java-how-can-i-compile-an-entire-directory-structure-of-code)

In the javac command line, how to compile whole source dir with wildcard ?

```
javac src\com\mq\Main.java
```

changed to

```
javac src\*
```

can we do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Ant?  It makes this kind of thing much simpler.  See:  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html#srcdirnote

You just point it to the top level of your source tree, then you can selectively exclude anything you don't want to compile.  You can also get more complicated if you need to, but that handles most common needs.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a wildcard :

```
javac src\com\mq\*.java
```

Comment: This will not work directly for multiple packages.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the @args technique, as defines in the [javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile). It's a file containing the paths of the classes to compile.

If you use a linux/unix system, it's easy to create such a file :

```
find . -iname *.java > files.txt
javac @files.txt
```

It works recursively, just launch it at the root of your source directory.

Comment: On windows the list of files to compile can be obtained by: dir /b /s  | findstr \.java > files.txt

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no

Longer answer: maybe
The javac command will compile all the files you list on the command line.  If, using wildcards, you can create a list of all files in your src tree on the javac command line, the it will compile all of them.

On UNIX you can do something like this:

```
find src -type f -name "*.java" -print | xargs javac
```

One of the answers to the question of which this question is a duplicate ([Java: How can I compile an entire directory structure of code ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764768/java-how-can-i-compile-an-entire-directory-structure-of-code) from the Chip McCormick comment) demonstrates a find that uses the -exec parameter.  For a large number of .java files that technique is better.  For a small number of .java files I believe the one I show is effectively the same as the technique with the -exec parameter.

Answer (score -1):

use cd command to go to the directory containing source files. then issue the command
**javac *.java**

Comment: This is not a good idea if one is using several packages.

Comment: then how can i compile in that situation?

Comment: Have a look at one of the other answers, most of them work.

Answer (score -1):

The *"right way"* to do this would be to use a build tool like Ant or Maven or an IDE, which does this automatically for you.

For example, in Ant, you would use this task in your compile target:

```
<javac srcdir="src"
       encoding="UTF-8"
       destdir="classes">
</javac>
```