# Trying to create a package for my java application

Tags: linux, packaging, java

I am in the process of putting together a simple RPG game engine in java. At this point everything works fine while all my classes are in one directory. Basically, I know I am going to end up with a heap of files and wish to organise them into a package structure. I followed the directions at http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html but can't seem to make the magic happen. The two classes posted are the least dependent of the lot and I figure if I can get these working then the rest shouldn't be a drama. For the record I am using openJDK in Leeenux (remix of Ubuntu netbook Remix)

First class

```
package adventure.engine;

import java.util.*;

public class Inventory
{
ArrayList itemList = new ArrayList();

public Inventory()
{

}

public void addItem()
{

}

public void removeItem()
{

}
}
```

And the second:

```
package adventure.engine;



import adventure.engine.*;



public class PlayerCharacter

{

private String name = "Player";

private String race;

private String plrClass;

private int level;

private int xp;

private int levelXp;

private Inventory inventory = new Inventory();



//---------

//Abilities

//---------



private static final String[] abilitiesList = {"Strength",

                    "Dexterity",

                    "Constitution",

                    "Intelligence",

                    "Wisdom",

                    "Charisma"};



private int[] abilitiesValues = new int[abilitiesList.length];



//------

//Skills

//------

private static final String[] skillsList    = {"Acrobatics"     , "Insight",

                    "Arcana"            , "Intimidate",

                    "Athletics"         , "Nature",

                    "Bluff"         , "Perception",

                    "Diplomacy"     , "Religion",

                    "Dungeoneering"     , "Stealth",

                    "Endurance"     , "Streetwise",

                    "Heal"          , "Thievery",

                    "History"};



private int[] skillsValues = new int[skillsList.length];



//***********

//Constructor

//***********

public PlayerCharacter()

{

    level = 1;

    xp = 0;

    levelXp = 1000;



    setAbility("Strength", 8);

    setAbility("Dexterity", 10);

    setAbility("Constitution", 10);

    setAbility("Intelligence", 10);

    setAbility("Wisdom", 10);

    setAbility("Charisma", 10);

}       //public PlayerSheet()





//*************

//Class Methods

//*************

public void addXp(int val)

{

    xp += val;



    if (xp >= levelXp)

    {

        level++;

        xp -= levelXp;

        //levelXp += ;

    }

}       //public void addXp(int val)





public void updateSkills()

{



}





//Mutators

public void setName(String n)

{

    name = n;

}





public void setLevel(int l)

{

    level = l;

}



public void setRace(String r)

{

    race = r;

}



public void setXP(int x)

{

    xp = x;

}





public void setClass(String c)

{

    plrClass = c;

}



//set ability value by name

public void setAbility(String a, int val)

{

    for(int i = 0; i < abilitiesList.length; i++)

    {

        if(abilitiesList[i].compareTo(a) == 0)

        {

            abilitiesValues[i] = val;

        }

    }

}



//set ability by index

public void setAbility(int index, int val)

{

    abilitiesValues[index] = val;

}



//set skill by name

public void setSkill(String name, int val)

{

    for(int i = 0; i < skillsList.length; i++)

    {

        if(skillsList[i].compareTo(name) == 0)

        {

            skillsValues[i] = val;

        }

    }

}



//set skill by index

public void setSkill(int index, int val)

{

    skillsValues[index] = val;

}



//Accessors

public static String[] getAbilityList()

{

    return abilitiesList;

}



public static String[] getSkillsList()

{

    return skillsList;

}



//retrieve an ability value by name

public int getAbility(String a)

{

    int val = 0;



    for(int i = 0; i < abilitiesList.length; i++)

    {

        if(abilitiesList[i].compareTo(a) == 0)

        {

            val = abilitiesValues[i];

            break;

        }

    }



    return val;

}



//retrieve an ability value by index number

public int getAbility(int i)

{

    return abilitiesValues[i];

}



public int getSkill(String s)

{

    int val = 0;



    for(int i = 0; i < skillsList.length; i++)

    {

        if(skillsList[i].compareTo(s) == 0)

        {

            val = skillsValues[i];

            break;

        }

    }



    return val;

}



public int getSkill(int i)

{

    return skillsValues[i];

}



public String getName()

{

    return name;

}



public String getRace()

{

    return race;

}



public String getPlrClass()

{

    return plrClass;

}



public int getLevel()

{

    return level;

}



public int getXP()

{

    return xp;

}



public int getLevelXP()

{

    return levelXp;

}



}       //public class PlayerCharacter
```

Classes reside in /home/user/Java/adventure/engine

Output from echo $classpath is /home/james/Java:/.:

when I attempt to compile the second class I get the following error:

```
PlayerCharacter.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Inventory
location: class adventure.engine.PlayerCharacter
    private Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
            ^
PlayerCharacter.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Inventory
location: class adventure.engine.PlayerCharacter
private Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
```

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.How to solve this?

Comment: Why do you compile source files manually (and one by one)? Try something like maven or ant or another build tool.

Comment: My introduction to java has been through my uni studies. At this stage they have us compiling manually. I'll take any suggestions to make this easier. I'll check it out.

Comment: Please explain the directory from where you are executing the javac and also the javac command you are executing. This may help to solve your issue

Comment: Thanks guys, I think the problem is solved.

Comment: can you edit the post with "how you are compiling the classes?"

Comment: if you think problem is solved. please answer your own question. regards

Comment: answer was provided by another user and has been marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

> 1) You might not have compiled Inventory
>   2) PlayerCharacter and Inventory are in same package. So there is no need to import.

You should be compiling them as

> javac adventure/engine/Inventory.java
>
> javac adventure/engine/PlayerCharacter.java

Comment: Inventory is compiled.
Tried removing the import, still the same error.

Comment: You can also use wildcards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764768/java-how-can-i-compile-an-entire-directory-structure-of-code?lq=1

Comment: Sweet as. no errors compiling from a terminal with that setup. Using SCite as my editor so I was just using it's default compile option. Thanks.