# Java: Classes do not find each other in package (factory design pattern)

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I have three different classes:

#### Woman.java

```
package human;
public class Woman extends Human{
    private final String pnr;
    private final String namn;

    public Woman(String n, String p){
        namn = n;
        pnr = p;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "My name is "+namn+" and I am a woman.";
    }

}
```

#### Man.java

```
package human;
public class Man extends Human{
    private final String pnr;
    private final String namn;

    public Man(String n, String p){
        namn = n;
        pnr = p;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "My name is "+namn+" and I am a man.";
    }   
}
```

#### Human.java

```
package human;
public abstract class Human{
    public static Human create(String namn, String pnr){
        char nastsist_char = pnr.charAt(9); // takes second last char in pnr
        String nastsist_string = Character.toString(nastsist_char);
        float siffra = Float.parseFloat(nastsist_string);   //Converts to float
        if ((siffra % 2) == 0){                 //Checks if even
            return new Man(namn, pnr);          
        }
        else{
            return new Woman(namn, pnr);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the file Human.java, I get the error

> cannot find symbol: class Man,

and

> cannot find symbol: class Woman.

When I try to compile the file Man.java or Woman.java, I get the error

> cannot find symbol: class Human.

No changing of `public/private` visibility of the classes have helped. All the files are located in a directory called `human`.

What is the problem here?

I should add that the goal I'm trying to achieve is to have an abstract class Human that can not be instantiated, and in that class I want to have a create method that returns instances of either Man or Woman depending on `pnr`. Also, I do not want Man or Woman to be possible to instantiate in any other way than through the create method.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to compile the entire project, rather than just singular classes.

Comment: Compile Human first and then compile the other classes.

Comment: I understand that you are just starting with Java, but still; the names that you are using for your variables could be dramatically improved. "namn", "pnr" are just confusing; why not calling them "firstName" and "lastName" or something alike. And from a design point of view: having an abstract base class that knows its concrete subclasses is not a good idea; and beyond that: when you are already having an abstract base class that represents humans; why do Man and Wife each have namn and pnr? Put those into Human; and provide getters there!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think an abstract class cannot have a static method. Because the static method uses a static instance of himself and you can't build an instance of an abstract class. So you have to place your factory method in a Factory class and then compile the hole package.

Comment: Jägermeister: They are called so because I'm taking a course in swedish. I edited the comments so that you can understand them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with your code or packaging, so the problem is elsewhere. How do you compile? I'm guessing you might be doing

```
javac human/Human.java
```

which will not work, since `Man` and `Woman` is then not on the classpath and thus not known to the Java compiler when working on `Human`. You should include these when compiling:

```
javac human/*.java
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, it sorted the problem out.

Comment: A `.class` file cannot be on the classpath if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you compile them by yourself, in a terminal or something?
Try to compile all files all together then:

```
javac Man.java Woman.java Human.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You have cycles in the classes. So you have two choices.
1) Compile all together
2) Create a new class e.g. Factory and instantiate the objects there

It's never a good idea to create cycles in you code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried : `javac *.java` in your folder ?

[Java: How can I compile an entire directory structure of code ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764768/java-how-can-i-compile-an-entire-directory-structure-of-code)

Comment: Actually, that would also fail since there would be a discrepancy between file path and package name, but the idea is right...

Comment: Right, javac human/*.java answers the question as you mentionned above