# Javac compiler not recognizing wildcard?

Tags: java, docker, javac

I set up a folder containing a test java file that only contains the word "test". I want docker to compile it. To run it, I call

```
$ docker run -it -v ~/my/path/testpayload:/payload -w /payload test_docker javac -cp /usr/share/java/*:. *.java
```

However, I get the following error

```
javac: file not found: *.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

If I explicitly state the name of the java file like so:

```
$ docker run -it -v ~/my/path/testpayload:/payload -w /payload test_docker javac -cp /usr/share/java/*:. TestPayload.java
```

It tries to compile and returns with the expected error:

```
TestPayload.java:1: error: reached end of file while parsing
test
^
1 error
```

I tried it again with the wildcard but without the classpath and it still doesn't work, which makes me think it's something with the wildcard, I googled but it seems to me like I'm using the wildcard correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764768/java-how-can-i-compile-an-entire-directory-structure-of-code

Comment: `javac $(find . -name "*.java")`