# Package ... does not exist error in intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new in Java and can not get idea of using packages.
Am I stupid or is this some kind of bug?

Guys, how to deal with this error?

```
C:\Users\batievskiy\IdeaProjects\JavaPset\src>java Test.java
Test.java:1: error: package pkgcalculate does not exist
import pkgcalculate.Calculator;
                   ^
Test.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Calculator obj = new Calculator();
        ^
  symbol:   class Calculator
  location: class Test
Test.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Calculator obj = new Calculator();
                             ^
  symbol:   class Calculator
  location: class Test
3 errors
error: compilation failed
```

[image]

this is Calculator code:

```
package pkgcalculate;

public class Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calculator obj = new Calculator();
        System.out.println(obj.add(10, 20));
    }
}
```

from what I got: that I cannot run Test.java from the terminal directly using: java Test.java But if I run Test with Shift + F10, the program is compiled. Why is that? Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: what does the package statement in Calculator say? please show code, instead of images

Comment: personally, if you are just starting, I would recommend against immediately starting with a professional IDE.

Comment: I suspect that the classpath is missing - are you able to run the class file in the IDE by right clicking the source code and clicking on "run"?

Comment: I don't see an error in the code, anyway

Comment: there no errors in the code. But when I.m trying: java Test.java
it gives me terminal error: package pkgcalculate does not exist

Comment: @Batiievskyi Try giving it the classpath. And you don't run `java` on a source file.

Comment: from what I got: this is that I cannot run Test.java from the terminal directly using: java Test.java
But if I run Test with Shift + F10, the program is compiled. Why is that? Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: I would love to use Eclipse instead. But JavaRush course and Nix Solutions Java course force us to use and get used to professional Intellij IDE

Answer (score 1):

If you compiling your code from command line you have to compile classes you depend on first.

Or compile them all together in one go.

Comment: Thanks a lot.)

Is it possible to run it from the terminal? or will only Shift + F10 start the program?

Comment: I found duplicate for yo question. There is good explanation in answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764768/java-how-can-i-compile-an-entire-directory-structure-of-code

Comment: Talex, Thanks for this link.) There are more than enough information for me by now.  Especially how to use terminal in what I'm interested in. I'm really appreciate your help.)